# How could I include a variable in a here document?

Tags: shell, cat, here-document

I am trying to use a user-defined global variable in a `cat <<eof>> filename` situation, but it's not working. I found what I want in simple `cat << eof` examples on this forum, which led me here: http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/here-docs.html. But I would like to to something like the following, with the added `>>` and `filename` (This does **not** work.):

```
#!/bin/bash

#after testing I will define this in .bashrc or somewhere?
set IP_ADDR = "123.123.123.123"

#empty the file in case there is something in it
truncate -s 0 sample.conf

# open a file and append
cat <<EOF >> sample.conf
  This is my sample config file
  Server IP = $IP_ADDR
  this is the last line of my sample config file
EOF

#print the file to verify
cat sample.conf
```

This produces a null string after `Server IP =`

`sed` would work if I already had the file written except for the missing variable value, but I won't necessarily have the IP address (or whatever) readily available as a literal string.

Also, I might not have the literal string available for use as a command line parameter when I run the script. `$1` does work within the `cat << eof >> filename` code block. I proved that. But I won't have immediate access to the value when I start this script...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
set IP_ADDR = "123.123.123.123"
```

is incorrect. You need:

```
IP_ADDR="123.123.123.123"
```

(without spaces).